# python get docstring from terminal using option

Tags: python, docstring

Let us say I have a file

myfile.py

```
"""
long documentation of myfile.py
...
"""

# tons of stuf
# this include some functions and their documentation
```

and I would like to do

```
bash $ python myfile.py -h
```

such that it displays all the documentation but does not execute the `tons of stuff`. (I don't care if the option is `--help` instead of `-h`.)

I am pretty sure I have already seen it somewhere but I can't find it. Is it related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689279/parsing-argument-in-python) and to [this second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123660/python-help-function-printing-docstrings)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
argparse
```

Using `argparse`, You can display the `__doc__` string by passing it to the description parameter of Argparse

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
long documentation of myfile.py
...
"""


# tons of stuf
# this include some functions and their documentation
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    # Add your arguments here
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="myFilenameVariable",
                        required=True,
                        help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.myFilenameVariable)
```

Run the python file

```
$ python myfile.py --help
```